# My MacBook Pro disconnects from the WiFi when not in use

Tags: mac, wifi, internet

I usually download large files overnight but recently I had my mac formatted so all the settings were lost. I not that much of a techie person and I tried adjusting the settings and all but I don't really know what I'm supposed to do.

After I start my downloads, I plug my mac to its power adapter and dim the screen. To my surprise, the wifi gets disconnected when my mac is not in use thus stopping all my downloads. HOW DO I PREVENT MY MAC FROM DISCONNECTING FROM THE WIFI?

Here are my energy saver settings and I currently use Yosemite:
[image: Here are my energy settings:]

Comment: You might want to use one of these: [Caffeine](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/24120/caffeine), [Amphetamine](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/amphetamine/id937984704?mt=12) or [Wimoweh](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/wimoweh/id610341008?mt=12). Wimoweh is the more automatic solution where as the other two, that basically do the same thing, are slightly more manual one click solutions for preventing mac from sleeping when active. Although Amphetamine can detect if a single application is running. I've personally used Caffeine a lot in the past when downloading large files.

Comment: I worded that poorly. Amphetamine basically has automatic deactivation feature if an application that you define is closed. However, it doesn't activate itself automatically when you open the application again (for what ever reason), like Wimoweh does.

Answer (score 1):

Try unchecking "put hard disks to sleep when possible"